# Razor view engine pass data from layout to content

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, razorengine

I am using razor view engine outside of mvc framework. Before you wonder, there are some project specific reasons.

So While adding pages, I add .cshtml layout and content page.
The question is without mvc framework(which takes out possibility of viewback,tempdata) , How can I access variable/data on layout page in content cshtml page? For example:
 If I have in layout

@data=DB.GetData()

Then Can I have @data accessible in content .cshtml page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PageData` dictionary:

```
@{PageData["data"] = DB.GetData();}
```

or if you are a fan of dynamic stuff:

```
@{Page.data = DB.GetData();}
```

Comment: works well. Are there any more ways?  just being curious